# Creating a save as and send command button in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to minimize a daily task by creating a form that will have a save as/send command button. After searching similar posts, I found the code below:

**How do I define the "TagNum", "Date" and "NTID"?**

```
strTagNum = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("TagNum")(1).Range.Text
strNTID = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("NTID")(1).Range.Text
strDate = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Date")(1).Range.Text
Dim strFilename As String
strFilename = strTagNum & "_" & strNTID & "_" & Format(strDate, "ddmmyyyy") & ".docx"
Email_Send_To = strNTID & "@example.com"
```

Comment: In your code "TagNum", "NTID" and "Date" are three ContentControls in the active document (google for `ContentControl`). The names can be changed to suit your own need, and the controls could be TextBoxes in your form. In the code, two of the three values are concatenated to make up a file name. The third is the recipient in the email address. For your purposes all you need is a file name and a recipient. You might create or obtain both in a manner totally different from the above.